# Is it good or bad practice to use HTML classes to assign CSS

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project where the development team has outsourced their graphics work to a 3rd party. The CSS files the 3rd party developed are filled with code that allows the developers to assign single CSS declarations to HTML elements using HTML classes.

For example:

```
.padding-bottom-10 {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

I have two questions:

1. Would this setup be considered lazy programming?
2. Is this setup commonplace?

Comment: It's not lazy programming and it's reusable. It follows the basic principle of css. So why not..

Comment: The only answers you are going to get are purely based on opinion.

Comment: Philibobby is correct, _except_ if you plan to create a class for every css rule, as one might come to think when looking at your example.

Comment: the apparent naming convention defies a central tenet of a hierarchical attribute system like css and separation of structure and presentation - just imho, of course

Comment: I do not believe this to be opinion-based: http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/goodclassnames The issue with these non-semantic class names is that they will make no sense if the design changes in future, or isn't relevant in a particular responsive design. If that element no longer requires a bottom padding of 10px, then it will need to be re-written as something like `.padding-bottom-10 { padding-bottom: 0; }` which is non-sensical.

Comment: Yes, opinion-based: Sadly it is kinda commonplace, as this is advertised by popular CSS “frameworks” like f.e. bootstrap. But it violates the separation of concerns – once you want to _change_ the formatting of a certain HTML element, you begin to swap out classes (whereas in an ideal world, you would leave the HTML alone, and only change the CSS).

Comment: I should point out that this is not uncommon, even among some of the best web frameworks out there. I wouldn't want to be accused of being an absolutist, but I would strive for semantic meaning where possible.

Comment: Your example is pretty lazy, but good class names as well as consistent and well-designed base element styles are the basis of good stylesheets.

Comment: @ChrisHardie - you can accuse me of being an absolutist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a modifier in the OOCSS methodology.

It promotes the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle of software development. When applied correctly, it improves maintainability as that specific property-value pair is not repeated in other parts of the code.

However, your example's naming is rather poor. `padding-bottom-small` or `padding-bottom-med` would be an improvement and more future-proof, as that given constant value may change sometime and the constant in the name would no longer be accurate.

There's indeed a drawback in adding non-semantic class names to the markup, which makes the HTML harder to maintain. The DRY benefits usually overweight this drawback though. Also, pre-processors allow for OOCSS development purely in the CSS (e.g. with Sass' [`@extend` directive](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend) and Less' [`:extend` pseudo-class](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature)), without polluting the markup with the non-semantic class names.

### *References*

- [**Methods for Modifying Objects in OOCSS**](http://oliverjash.me/2012/09/07/methods-for-modifying-objects-in-oocss.html)
- [**OOCSS + Sass = The best way to CSS by Ian Storm Taylor**](http://ianstormtaylor.com/oocss-plus-sass-is-the-best-way-to-css/)

---

### NOTE

This is just part of a paradigm to write efficient CSS. Whether it is the best for your use case boils down to the application needs and developers' preference.

Comment: Clearly this is a common methodology for developing CSS, and, if implemented with forethought, quite powerful. My specific example is one of 100+ classes with a single CSS declaration, so I'm willing to guess this is an extreme example that doesn't quite embrace OOCSS.

Comment: I personally dislike unused classes as it wastes some bandwidth (I usually create modifiers as I need them), but having a readily-made set of re-usable modifiers is not too bad. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

You must be aware of the following note in [the spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors3/#class-html) when (ab)using class selectors:

> Because CSS gives considerable power to the "class" attribute, authors
>   could conceivably design their own "document language" based on
>   elements with almost no associated presentation (such as DIV and SPAN
>   in HTML) and assigning style information through the "class"
>   attribute. Authors should avoid this practice since the structural
>   elements of a document language often have recognized and accepted
>   meanings and author-defined classes may not.

But yes, abusing class selectors is common place.

Answer (score 0):

Why not ? If you are targetting your webpage into really old retarded versions of IE, using them is sometimes nessescary. For example IE 6 does not know direct child selector ( > ), 7 and 8 still don't know about :last-child and many more....

Answer (score 0):

If multiple classes that define just one thing are to be used on lots of elements then we may as well time warp back to the 90s and start using `<font face="sans-serif" color="red" size="4"><b><u><i>A bit of text and stuff</i></u></b></font>` because restyling a site or even part of it would require time that could be better used for drinking beer if proper classes had been used.